# Python Reading CSV and sending to function

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to build a python script that a user can pass the filename from the command line but for some reason the filename is not being recognized providing errors when it comes time for the csv loop to read the file. If I put the name of the file statically, the script works with no issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, getopt, re, csv

def pushname(firstname, lastname, dob):
    print firstname + '\n'
    print lastname + '\n'
    print dob + '\n'

def printUsage():
    print 'script.py -f <inputfile>'

def main(argv):
    firstname = ''; lastname = ''; dob = ''; csvfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"?fn:ln:dob:f",["fistname",
        "lastname", "dob", "csvfile="])`
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        printUsage()
        sys.exit(2)

    if len(opts) == 0:
        printUsage()
        sys.exit(0)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-f", "--file"):
            csvfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-fn"):
            firstname = arg
        elif opt in ("-ln"):
            lastname = arg
        elif opt in ("-dob"):
            dob = arg

        print csvfile
        with open(csvfile, 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                firstname = row['firstname']
                lastname = row['lastname']
                dob = row['dob']
                pushname(firstname, lastname, dob)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 37, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "script.py", line 46, in main
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as file:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: ''
```

Comment: "providing errors" like what?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - I updated the question with the error I'm seeing

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - Before I didn't have (csvfile, 'r'), I changed it from (csvfile)

Comment: It says that either the mode or filename are invalid. The mode is `'r'`, which is fine, and the filename is `''`, the empty string, which is not fine. Have you tried unindenting the entire `with` block by one level so it's not in the loop?

Comment: You also misspelled `firstname` as `fistname` once.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - I just tried unindenting the with loop and now the error I'm getting is: NameError: name 'csvfile' is not defined

Comment: I said "by one level." Just one.

Comment: I tried that before going more than 1 level and I was getting the same error in the question like before.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 btw. I'm calling the script by going python scripts.py -f list.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"?fn:ln:dob:f",["fistname", "lastname", "dob", "csvfile="])` is wrong. Especially the `"?fn:ln:dob:f"`. This expression specifies the short options which must consist of only one unique letter. Letters followed by a colon specify options which expect an argument. You do the following:

- `?f` Define options `?`, `f`, without arguments
- `n:` Define option `n`, expecting an argument
- `l` Define `l`, without argument
- `n:` Redefine `n`, expecting an argument
- `do` Define `d`, `o`, each without argument
- `b:` Define `b`, expecting an argument
- `f` Redefine `f`, without argument

The filename switch `f` is defined without argument.

You could replace `"?fn:ln:dob:f"` by `"n:l:d:f:?"` with n, l, d, and f being name (first name), last name, dob, and filename, respectively.

Check your result by putting a `print(opts); print(args)` just after the `getopt`-line like in this test.py:

```
# test.py

import sys
import getopt

opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "?fn:ln:dob:f", ["fistname", "lastname", "dob", "csvfile="])
print("before: ", opts, args)

opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "n:l:d:f:?", ["firstname", "lastname", "dob", "filename"])
print("after: ", opts, args)
```

This should give the following output:

```
maij@host$ python test.py -f 1 -l 2 -d 3 -n 4 -? 5
('before: ', [('-f', '')], ['1', '-l', '2', '-d', '3', '-n', '4', '-?', '5'])
('after: ', [('-f', '1'), ('-l', '2'), ('-d', '3'), ('-n', '4'), ('-?', '')], ['5'])

maij@host$
```

Comment: I went ahead and corrected the expression as you mentioned and I also did a print for opts and args and this is the result i'm getting [('-f', '')]
['list.csv']

Comment: If I call the script using script.py -n john -l doe the print for opts and args is [('-n', 'john'), ('-l', 'doe')][]

Comment: The description was not correct, the answer is updated.